# Google Cloud signed URL invalidation

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The [Google Cloud signed URL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) says:

"Anyone who knows the URL can access the resource until the expiration time for the URL is reached or the key used to sign the URL is rotated." How can I tell which key was used to sign a URL, and when it will be rotated? If I am using a service account to create the signed URL, is the service account's key the key used to sign the URL?

Also, if I create a signed URL for file A, and then several minutes later create a second signed URL for file A, are both signed URLs valid? Or does the first signed URL become invalidated after the second is created?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/creating-signatures

This page says, "Important: The Google-managed service account keys used by the signBlob method are rotated regularly. If you set an expiration time for a signature that is greater than 12 hours and generate the signature using the signBlob method, the signature is usable for at least 12 hours, but might stop working prior to the expiration time due to key rotation. Signatures generated using the signBlob method are best used for short-lived access to resources."

so I think expirations over 12 hours are unreliable.

Comment: Assuming that you're using a service account key to sign the URL, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell which key was used to sign a URL, and when it will be
> rotated?

The identity used to sign the URL is included in the Signed URL parameter key `X-Goog-Credential`.

> If I am using a service account to create the signed URL, is the
> service account's key the key used to sign the URL?

Yes, the service account's RSA private key is used.

> Also, if I create a signed URL for file A, and then several minutes
> later create a second signed URL for file A, are both signed URLs
> valid? Or does the first signed URL become invalidated after the
> second is created?

Both Signed URLs are valid. Creating a new Signed URL does not invalidate a previous one.